# Is there a recommended method to clean up Azure Data Factory (Datasets, linked services etc.)?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Elaborating the title further, the current ADF I am working on has a lot of *legacy code*, i.e. multiple datasets, linked services. Unfortunately no naming convention or system of creating new items were defined.

1. I have tried to list down all the pipelines, the associated datasets (linked services as well), but this seems a lengthy approach and we have around 100 odd pipelines.
2. I tried by exporting the complete data factory as an ARM template and tried to create a parser which would automatically create the above list, but it seems that ARM templates are more interlinked than I had thought, I dropped this plan.

Is their a better approach for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the pipelines/dataflows that uses the particular dataset. this details will be available in the properties tab -> Related tab.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbka4.png)

Also you get the list of datasets that uses a particular linked service by going to manage tab ->Linkedservice -> Related
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCBtW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned data factory version (v1 or v2) and mentioned it has  lot of legacy code, I am making an assumption that it could be a v1 factory. In that case, you can check the [ADF v1 to ADF v2 migration](https://azuredatafactoryv2.github.io/v1tov2migration/) tool which helps with basic migration tasks (listing resources, doing simple migration steps etc.)